# Cannot iterate through array in xamarin forms (C#)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a string array and I am trying to iterate though it using foreach, however it doesn't even recognize the variable I used for the array.

Here is the code I have:

```
public class test
{
    string[] letters = new string[5] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };

    foreach (string i in letters)
        Debug.WriteLine(i);
}
```

It says the name 'lower' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Are you sure it is not another part of your code that is causing issues? What you have written there looks perfectly fine, apart from a missing semicolon after WriteLine.

Comment: Yeah I didn't make any other changes to it. (I edited the question the include the semi colon, thanks)

Comment: Also your code in your class should go into a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined a class, but you haven't defined a method. The code you refer to should be defined in a method. You should get a warning for this by visual studio if this is your editor.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void YourMethodName()
    {
        var letters = new [] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };

        foreach (var letter in letters)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(letter);
        }
    }
}
```

Then by calling this as below:

```
Test.YourMethodName();
```

You will get the expected output.

Comment: Thank you! Very silly mistake on my part, didn't have a method!